# Where do Naruto's movies fall between episodes (I want to know the certain number of episodes that must be watch before each movie

Tags: naruto

I would like to know a certain number of episodes before attending each movie. I have seen similar questions, but they do not answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Naruto Movies:

Movie 1 ("Ninja Clash in the Land of Snow"): after Naruto learns Rasengan.

Movie 2 ("Legend of the Stone of Gelel"): after Tsunade becomes Hokage.

Movie 3 ("Guardians of the Crescent Moon Kingdom"): after Sasuke escaped Konaha.

#### Naruto Shippuden Movies

Movie 1 ("Naruto Shippuden the Movie"): after Naruto returns to Konaha.

Movie 2 ("Bonds") & 3 ("The Will of Fire"): after Naruto meets Sasuke at Orochimaru's hideout.

Movie 4 ("The Lost Tower"): after Naruto learns Rasenshuriken.

Movie 5 ("Blood Prison"): after Naruto learns Sage mode and defeats Pain.

Movie 6 ("Road to Ninja"): before the Fourth Shinobi World War.

Movie 7 ("The Last"): after the Fourth Shinobi World War.

#### Boruto Movie(s):

Boruto ("Boruto"): after Naruto becomes Hokage.

**Feel free to edit if I made a mistake!**

Comment: please can you write the full names of the movies

Comment: i think there is more movies of naruto like: (Naruto x UT),                                                         (Naruto:naruto: finally a clash!! jounin vs. genin),                                                                         (Naruto: find the crimson four leaf clover),                                                                      (Naruto:the last story-mission: protect the waterfall village),                                   (Naruto: honoo no chuunin shiken! Naruto vs. Konohamaru!!),                                  (Naruto: shippuden-jump super anime tour 2013 special)

Comment: @Mikha please do not post illegal links, we do not support piracy on this site